# Plugin not recognizing "this" jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to get my plugin to recognize the element which it is called from such as:

```
(function($) {
    $('#element').myPlugin({});
})($)
```

On a different page -

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
        var element = $(this);
        $.post('connection.php',{},
            function(output) {
                element.html(output);
            });
    }
})($)
```

But it for some reason is not working.. i am puzzled

HTML page:

```
<body>
    <div id="element">adsf</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there an error? If so, what? What is the html? Does `#element` exist in the DOM?

Comment: there is not error. it just does not recognize that there is `#element` in the page. when i `alert(element.html());` it display "**null**"

Comment: Does the element exist in the DOM?

Comment: Please post the relevant html **and script call site**.

Comment: Incidentally, there is little point in passing the outer `$` as an argument of the same name to your immediately-executing function. You might as well just reference the outer `$`. More common is to pass `jQuery` (not `$`) and receive *that* as `$`.

Comment: The code you posted *will* match the element. Ensure the invocation to it is inside a document-ready handler.

Comment: @Utkanos is there a difference? I just always used it like this and works fine.

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Post the script call site.

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua - yes it works fine, it's just there's no point in it. The other way is often used in conjunction with `jQuery.noConflict()` as a means of preventing jQuery from conflicting with other libraries BUT still allowing the use of `$`, as a local variable.

Comment: @asawyer the call site is as posted. its under the same type of document-ready as the `$.fn.myPlugin` is

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Thank you! Most likely the problem is the script is runnign before the DOM is ready. Wrap the plugin in the document onReady event. `$(function(){ ... });`  As this works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/bx944/

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Unless there is more script you are not telling us, no it is not.

Comment: no there is not. so take all the code that i have and put it in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` ?

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Did you see the jsFiddle link I gave?

Comment: yes sorry it works now! thank you :) if you would like to post everything you wrote in comment as an answer i would like to give you the correct answer

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua I'm glad to help, in the future through, please try to give as much information as possible up front in the question, including a short reproducible example of the problem. That way we don't have to spend 20 minutes teasing it out of ya! :-) Good luck!

Comment: no in your answer just say to wrap the call to the plugin in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` this is what you told me to do here

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua That may be the exact solution but I'm also trying to write an answer that may help anyone else with this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's throwing you off is that this:

```
(function($) {
    $('#element').myPlugin({});
})($)
```

Is not the same as this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#element').myPlugin({});
});
```

So everything was working, but the DOM element didn't exist yet as you expected it to.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is being called before the DOM is loaded. Try adding

```
   $(document).ready(function(){...your code..});
```